# SVN Freezes on Commit or Update

Tags: svn, centos

Running into a weird issue with SVN. I've got a CentOS 6.3 server running SVN version 1.6.11 using LDAP authentication for user login. It's been stable and online since July and has never had any issues. The system came down hard due to a power event in our data center during the hurricane and it hasn't been right since. The first commit to the server works properly but any attempted connection after that freezes and continues to try forever (or until the connection is terminated either by ending the client check-out process or stopping Apache). A reboot of the server allows a single check-in and then the freeze happens again. This appears to happen with TortoiseSVN, RapidSVN, and command-line SVN in CentOS. I'm down to basically two ideas to fix this at this point:

1. Dump and reload the existing SVN repositories and hope that whatever is causing it to hang doesn't carry over.
2. Restore from the last known good backup of the repositories.

Anyone run into this before and if so, how did you go about fixing it?

Comment: Never hit it, but it sounds like your repo may be corrupted. I'd try (1) first and then (2). If neither fixes it, you may be forced to reinstall your enviro/software and do (2) - hoping that changes since the power event aren't significant...

Comment: Why not test your repos first? `svn verify ...` -- But I don't think that's the problem. Use Sysinternals Process Explorer and try to find the hanging process. Maybe it shows interesting open file handles..??

Comment: process explorer isn't going to do much on CentOS.  Is there anything interesting in the apache logs during these episodes?  svnadmin verify is a great idea, what does it report? if something is amiss it will tell you which revision

Answer (score 1):

I found out that if your svn hangs it sometime means that your SVN client is too old.
Upgrade your svn client to meet the svn versioning of your svn server files.